# Playing an audio file while on the call in android / send a voice prompt so that other person can hear it?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I have read a few blogs about playing audio file so that other person can hear it but they are quiet a bit old. I was wondering if there were any updates/workarounds for this issue. If any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have access to the in-call audio stream from an Android application. The only "workaround" is if the device is in speakerphone mode -- what you play over the speaker can be picked up by the microphone, apparently.

Comment: Well the only problem is that, I am trying to develop app for network testing and so I cannot have any noise in it, which will occur in case of using speaker to do it. But anyways thanks for such a quick reply.