# how to make a call within android app?

Tags: android

I need to create some thing like prank call app so
which API should I used for developing the application in which user can call to any number with in app ?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by broadcasting specific intent
( see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html )

ACTION_DIAL displays dialer while ACTION_CALL actually places call.

Comment: I doublt it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498999/playing-an-audio-file-while-on-the-call-in-android-send-a-voice-prompt-so-that

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Intent` API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

Note your app will also need the permission to dial numbers.