# Working with DTMF tones in android

Tags: android, phone-call, dtmf

I want to do following in android.
Is it possible ?

1) call +xx xxxxxxx

2) wait to the first tone to end

3) insert pass: xxxx

4) wait for the short high tone to end

5) press 1 till you hear specific sound.

Here tones are DTMF tones and I tried to do it with call intent but how can i enter pass in ongoing call using code?

Can anybody guide me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: duplicate of [Play an audio clip onto an ongoing call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900564/play-an-audio-clip-onto-an-ongoing-call) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319949/need-to-play-audio-to-the-caller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452595/playing-an-pre-recorded-audio-file-to-somebody-over-a-call and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498999/playing-an-audio-file-while-on-the-call-in-android-send-a-voice-prompt-so-that and dozens upon dozens of others.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to do it directly from an Android device but you could use a programmable service that uses [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) to accomplish this. You would call the CCXML application which would in turn dial the phone number of the system you want to interact with. The CCXML application would then take over the automated process you describe. Listening for the tones, as described in your process, is often referred to as [Call Progress Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_progress_analysis). A platform that has a great CCXML and Call Progress Analysis is [Voxeo's Prophecy](http://evolution.voxeo.com/). You can try it out for free. Since you are listening for DTMF tones you may want to use a combination of CCXML and [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/). Prophecy supports both. VoiceXML can detect specific DTMF tones. There is no method for telling VoiceXML or CCXML to send DTMF. The way this is handles is playing audio recordings of DTMF. You can get [audio recordings of DTMF tones that work on Prophecy here](http://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/dtmf/index.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

Writing to phone call stream is not possible, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare and Alex Lockwood - actually, the well known inability to inject audio into a call is not a reason to think that sending DTMF tones is not possible.  Consider that devices do this all the time, in response to user keypress, while there's no known example of injecting arbitrary audio.  The question of being able to trigger that existing DTMF injection functionality is a quite different one from being able to inject arbitrary audio.  I suspect the answer is still be "no", but the reasons are different.  Having to get feedback from the microphone would also be a challenge.